# Renaming a tag based on id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a button that would modify the name inside the

tag but it does not work, i have tested it with a textbox and it works. here is my sample code:

```
<div data-role="content">

    <input type="text" id="NumberInput" data-clear-btn="true">
    <center><p id= "DisplayInput"> </p></center>
    <a data-role="button" onClick="modify( )">RENAME</a>

</div>              


<script>

    function modify( )
    {

    document.getElementById('NumberInput').value = "new input value";   
    document.getElementById('DisplayInput').value = "new display value";    

    }

</script>
```

only the textbox was renamed when i press the button and the

tag remained empty, is there something wrong with my code? This worked with javascript but i am required to convert it using jquery, i am still learing please bear with me.

Any help or advice will be glady accepted thanks in advance.

Comment: A `<p>` Element has no `value`.  If you want to change content inside of it use `innerHTML`.  Also I don't see where your function tries to "rename" anything. So I am not sure if that is what you really mean.

Comment: Aside: Don't use `<center>`. This is a deprecated element. Use CSS styles (`text-align:center;`) instead.

Comment: While everyone is suggesting `innerHTML` (since it is the most cross-browser compatible), the "correct" property would be [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) in this case, since you are only setting text instead of markup. Note you would have to use `innerHTML` to have markup processed and rendered. The `textContent` property, however, does not exist in IE8 and below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `innerHTML` property

```
  document.getElementById('DisplayInput').innerHTML = "new display value";
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/Yxy58/)

Answer (score 2):

`DisplayInput` is a paragraph. Since not an input element, it does not have `value`. However it has `innerHtml` you can use:

```
document.getElementById('DisplayInput').innerHtml = "new display value";
```

Comment: Thanks i was confused for awhile. this really helped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `innerHTML` property instead of `value` , since there is no value attribute for `p` tag

```
document.getElementById('DisplayInput').innerHTML = "new display value";
```